# Forcefully install package with pacman

Tags: software-installation, dependencies, pacman

What I want is pacman alternative command for this command:-

```
sudo dpkg --force-all -i somepackage.deb
```

I had dependencies installed manually but pacman tells me to install additional packages from Arch Linux's own repositories.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can skip dependency checks with `-d` or `--nodeps` or manually exclude specific packages from dependency checks with `--assume-installed` [see man page under transaction options](https://www.archlinux.org/pacman/pacman.8.html#_transaction_options_apply_to_em_s_em_em_r_em_and_em_u_em).